# Whats the best way to fill the missing data in a timeseries table, check for each sym and its lifespan?

Tags: kdb

Whats the best way to fill the missing data in a timeseries table?

I have a table say example below

```
//create sample data
tmp:([]date:`date$();sym:`symbol$();name:`symbol$();expiration_date:`date$());
//modify data to simulate requirement 
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH10;`someName1;2010.01.10)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH11;`someName2;2010.01.15)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH12;`someName3;2010.01.20)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH13;`someName4;2010.01.16)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH14;`someName5;2010.01.13)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);
{`tmp insert (x;`ESH15;`someName6;2010.01.28)} each (2010.01.01 + til 31);

//delete weekends
tmp:select from tmp where not (date mod 7) in 0 1

//modify data to simulate requirement 
tmp:delete from tmp where sym=`ESH10, date=2010.01.05;
tmp:delete from tmp where sym=`ESH11, date=2010.01.22;
tmp:delete from tmp where sym=`ESH12, date=2010.01.10;
tmp:delete from tmp where sym=`ESH15, date=2010.01.06;
```

Now I want to check for each symbol if there is an entry for that sym between the date (first_date_of_sym ; expiration_date), if its not present the copy from previous date.

So far I had come up with below solution but its not working.

1. get the lifespan of each sym. The lifespan will be (first_date_of_sym ; expiration_date)
2. generate the dates between those dates
3. check if date is present then dont do anything
4. if data is missing then copy from previous date
5. finally we will have a complete list of timeseries if data is missing in between then we had copied from previous date.

Lets take example

1. lifespan of ESH10 is (2010.01.01;2010.01.10), we are missing 2010.01.05, so backfill from 2010.01.04
2. lifespan of ESH11 is (2010.01.01;2010.01.15), we are missing 2010.01.22, falls out of lifespan, dont do anything
3. lifespan of ESH12 is (2010.01.01;2010.01.20), falls on weekend, we dont do anything
4. lifespan of ESH15 is (2010.01.01;2010.01.28), we are missing 2010.01.06, backfill from 2010.01.05

my sample code which is not working, this is something I came up with, but feel free to comeup with completely different approach that is also fine.

```
.qatest.fill_dates:{[res]
    //lets just get the fields we need
    res1:(select date, root, norm_sym, volume, open_int, voi:?[null volume;open_int;?[null open_int;volume;volume+open_int]], expiration_date from res);
    
    //get life of each symbol
    t1:0!select sd:first date, ed:last expiration_date by root, norm_sym from res1;
    
    raze {[res1;t1]
        //generate daterange for symbol start date and end date
        daterange:.dateutils.date_range[t1[`sd];t1[`ed]];
        //get weekdays only
        daterange:daterange where not (daterange mod 7) in 0 1;
        raze {[r;t;d]
            cnt:count select from r where date=d, norm_sym=t[`norm_sym];
            $[cnt;
                [
                    //no need to copy
                    r
                ];
                [
                    //need to copy from prev date
                    dataToCopy:select from r where date=.dateutils.prev_valid_date[d;`us], norm_sym=t[`norm_sym];
                    dataToCopy:update date:d from dataToCopy;
                    `date xasc r,dataToCopy
                ]
            ]
        }[res1;t1;] each daterange
    }[res1;] each t1
}
```

final output will be filled missing dates with previous value for each sym.
an exmaple

```
date        sym     name        expiration_date
2010-01-01  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-04  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-05  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10   //filled row
2010-01-06  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-07  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-08  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-11  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
2010-01-12  ESH10   someName1   2010-01-10
```

Comment: For the 2nd example you gave, do you still expect that row with date 2010.01.22 to appear in the output, but left empty? Or should it be removed?

Comment: should be removed, bec its out of lifespan of sym and we are not interested in it.

Comment: Thanks, my answer below should be what you're looking for then

Comment: yes, I am looking at your answer and trying to implement it in my code. Can you please help to explain your code last line?

Comment: so basically you are generating list of all syms and dates within lifespan  and then joining it with original tab and finally doing a fills. So fills will do fill forward or backward? we want to copy data from previous valid date

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fill/#fills - copies from preceding entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/ Find upper and lower bounds of range for each sym
dts:select min date,last expiration_date,dates:date by sym from tmp
/ Find valid set by removing dates on weekends
dts:update range:date+{x where not sum 1 2=\:mod[x;7]}each til each expiration_date-date from dts
/ Find dates that are missing from tmp for each sym
dts:flip get exec sym,last each except'[range;dates]from dts
/ Use date from previous day for each date that is missing, and join to tmp
tmp uj update date+1 from raze{[x;y]select from tmp where sym=x,date<y,i=(max;i)fby sym}.'dts
```

Comment: Last line should read `tmp uj update date+1 from raze...`

Comment: I edited my answer to make the change Cillian suggested. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much Cathal and Cillian for your answers. It helped alot solving my problem-set.

Comment: @CathalO'Neill  - The line where we find dates that are missing from tmp for each sym, this only works for last entry which is missing. Say ESH10  is missing in 20 times then we want to fill 10 dates which is missing ESH10. Right now only the last date where ESH10 is missing is getting fill, rest are not.

Comment: ah, what about if you change the last line to `tmp uj raze{[x;y]update date:y from$[any null y;;count[y]#]select from tmp where sym=x,date<last y,i=(max;i)fby sym}.'dts`?

Comment: I did something like  ```(.utils.custom_ungroup[`dates;select norm_sym,raze enlist each except'[range;dates]from dts])``` , testing it right now.

```.utils.custom_ungroup:{[col;tbl] @[tbl where count each tbl col;col;:;raze tbl col]};```

Answer (score 2):

If it's the case that we can exclude dates beyond a symbol's expiration date and weekends, then the following will work:

```
// filter weekends function
fw:{x where not(x mod 7)in 0 1}

// create a table with all dates in the appropriate window
// left join original data
// fill forward
fills(ungroup select fw first[date]+til first expiration_date-date by sym from tmp)lj`sym`date xkey tmp
```